# MySQL exception - com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I get the error:

> 'Unknown column 'customerno' in 'field list' '.

But, that column exists in my customer table. Then why am I getting this exception ?

Code:

```
import java.sql.*;  

public class Classy {  

    static String myQuery =   
            "SELECT customerno, name" +  
            "FROM customers;";  

    public static void main(String[]args)  
    {  
        String username = "cowboy";  
        String password = "1234567";  
        try  
        {  
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Business", username, password);  
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(myQuery);  

            while(rs.next())  
            {  
                System.out.print(rs.getString("customerno"));  
            }

        } catch(SQLException ex){System.out.println(ex);}  

    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your syntax is that **you have no space between `name` and `FROM`**

```
String myQuery =   
        "SELECT customerno, name" +  // problem is here
        "FROM customers;";
```

instead add a space after `name`

```
 String myQuery =   
        "SELECT customerno, name " +  // add space here
        "FROM customers";
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did not know that this kind of thing would not be handled by the API itself.

Comment: @sweetdreams: How could it be? You've just got a *string* - how is it meant to know that when you wrote "nameFROM" you meant "name FROM"? That's asking a bit much of an API...

Answer (score 4):

Look at what your query really is. This:

```
static String myQuery =   
        "SELECT customerno, name" +  
        "FROM customers;";
```

is equivalent to:

```
static String myQuery = "SELECT customerno, nameFROM customers;";
```

Now can you see what's wrong? I'm surprised it complained about `customerno` rather than the lack of a `FROM` part...

Note that I suspect you don't want the `;` either. I'd write it all one one line just for readability, when you can, as well as limiting the accessibility and making it final:

```
private static final String QUERY = "SELECT customerno, name FROM customers";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.*;  

public class Classy {  

static String myQuery =   
        "SELECT customerno, name" +  
        "FROM customers;";  

public static void main(String[]args)  
{  
    String username = "cowboy";  
    String password = "1234567";  
    try  
    {  
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Business", username, password);  
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(myQuery);  

        while(rs.next())  
        {
```

//Try and change this with the numeric value that is present in the database,
e.g if it's column 2 do something like 
rs.getString(1);

```
            System.out.print(rs.getString("customerno"));  
        }  


    }catch(SQLException ex){System.out.println(ex);}  

}  

}
```